# Template template parameter with typed parameters?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

The following code does not compile. *Is it even possible to pass an instance of `Configuration<t, u>` as a template parameter? (to profit from optimization of constant expressions)*

API:

```
template <int t, bool u>
struct Configuration {
  static constexpr int commonValue = t;
  static constexpr bool debug = u;
};

template <
  template<int t, bool u> Configuration<t, u> &conf,
  int x
>
class A {
public:
  int doSomething() {
    if (conf.debug) { // Optimize away if false
      // ...
    }
    return x * conf.commonValue; // Optimize to e.g. 6 with `conf.commonValue` =
                                 // 3, `x` = 2
  }
};
```

The user of the API should be able to do:

```
int main() {
    static constexpr Configuration<3, false> conf;
    A<conf, 2> a;
    A<conf, 5> b;
    A<conf, 8> c;
    std::cout << a.doSomething() << std::endl; // 6 (evaluated at compile time!)
    std::cout << b.doSomething() << std::endl; // 15
    std::cout << c.doSomething() << std::endl; // 24
}
```

Comment: Since you only have `static` attribute in `Configuration`, use a template type parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the attributes of `Configuration` are `static`, you should use a template type parameter<sup>1</sup>:

```
template <class ConfT, int x>
class A {
public:
  int doSomething() {
    if (ConfT::debug) { // Optimize away if false

    }
    return x * ConfT::commonValue;
  }
};
```

And then:

```
// Alias (not required):
using conf = Configuration<3, false>;

A<conf, 2> a;
A<conf, 3> b;
```

If you want non-static members, I don't think this is doable pre-C++17 (without passing template parameters of `Configuration` to  `A`), but in C++17 you could do<sup>1</sup>:

```
template <auto const& conf, int x>
class A {
public:
  int doSomething() {
    if (conf.debug) { // Optimize away if false
    }
    return x * conf.commonValue;
  }
};
```

But note that you can only pass references to variables with static storage duration.

<sub><sup>1</sup> In the first case, you can restrict the type to `Configuration<...>` by specializing `A`, in the second case, you can restrict the type of `conf` using an extra template parameter with `std::enable_if`.</sub>

---

You should also make the attributes `constexpr` in `Configuration`, not simply `const`:

```
template <int t, bool u>
struct Configuration {
  static constexpr int commonValue = t;
  static constexpr bool debug = u;
};
```

Comment: The 1st example does not compile with `g++ -std=C++17`. At `A<conf, 3> a;` it complains: `the value of ‘conf’ is not usable in a constant expression` With the 2nd example, at `template <auto const& conf, int x>`. the compiler complains: `‘auto’ parameter not permitted in this context`. Thanks for the suggestion about using `constexpr`! Although: Looking at assembly code I found that specifying `static const` is generally sufficient for `g++` to apply compile time optimizations. Nevertheless, I edited my question, replacing `const` with `constexpr` (as this distracts from the actual issue).

Comment: @feklee As I mentioned, for the second example, you need `conf` to have static storage duration, so typically not a local variable (unless you add a `static` modifier), see this example: https://godbolt.org/g/6Xd9hs Note that you need a quite recent version of gcc apparently (at least 7.1 according to godbolt).

Comment: @Holt Thanks, indeed the compiler I tested it with seems to have been too old. *What about the first example?* I cannot get it to compile at all. It would be nice to have sth. that works with C++11, but I have to accept it if that's not possible.

Comment: Well, the first example does work, if I replace `constexpr Configuration<3, false> conf;` with `typedef Configuration<3, false> conf;`. *Is that what you had in mind?*

Comment: @feklee Yes, exactly, I've added example of usage in the answer (`typedef` and `using` are the same thing here).